# Is there any sense of using full way to module when you already imported module directly?

Tags: python, import

In case of this importing:

`from app.settings import setting1`

1. `settings.setting1`
2. `setting1`

Are there cases when you need to use option 1 in your code, but option 2 does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from app.settings import setting1
settings.setting1  # error!
```

This does not work because `settings` is a name that was bounded to nothing. In the current scope, you only have defined `setting1`, `print(locals())` can confirm you that.

So I assume you meant instead :

```py
import app.settings as settings
from app.settings import setting1
# difference between :
setting1
# and :
settings.setting1 = 43
```

There is a subtle difference between the two.
By doing `from app.settings import setting1` you create a binding in the currect scope between the name `setting1` and the corresponding value from the `app.settings` module. This value gets copied. Whether this is a reference to a mutable object, or an immutable object, changes how you see changes made to it.
An exemple :

```py
# file: app/settings.py
setting1 = 80
```

```py
# file: main.py
import app.settings as settings
from app.settings import setting1
print(f"after import, setting1: {setting1}")                      # 80

settings.setting1 = 43
print(f"after assign n°1, module setting1: {settings.setting1}")  # 43
print(f"after assign n°1, local setting1: {setting1}")            # 80

setting1 = -11
print(f"after assign n°2, module setting1: {settings.setting1}")  # 43
print(f"after assign n°2, local setting1: {setting1}")            # -11
```

The import **copied** the value `80` and bound it to the `setting1` name in the current scope, while another value `80` lives in the module. They are distinct (because immutables) so that changing one does not affect the other.

But if I use a mutable object (for example a list), this is what I get :

```py
# file: app/settings.py
setting1 = [80]
```

```py
# file: main.py
import app.settings as settings
from app.settings import setting1
print(f"after import, setting1: {setting1}")                      # [80]

settings.setting1.append(43)
print(f"after append n°1, module setting1: {settings.setting1}")  # [80, 43]
print(f"after append n°1, local setting1: {setting1}")            # [80, 43]

setting1.append(-11)
print(f"after append n°2, module setting1: {settings.setting1}")  # [80, 43, -11]
print(f"after append n°2, local setting1: {setting1}")            # [80, 43, -11]
```

Here, using the local binding or the reference from the module changes nothing, they both are just a reference to a same mutable object.

I had problems with that once : I imported variables defined at the top-level of a mudule to share data, but when the import was `from my.module import my_shared_variable` a copy was (silently) created, and the data was actually not shared. So I had to use the first option because the second option was not doing what I wanted.

Apart from this mutable/immutable pitfall, if you are not doing tricky things with your imports, both are equivalent.